# wxapp becomes non-responsive after some time in mac

Tags: multithreading, macos, timer, wxwidgets, chromium-embedded

I have a wxApp implementation in which the wxFrame embeds a CEF browser.I have bindings from CEF framework to perform some Javascript bindings. The application shows up the initial screen and loads everything good. However, after a certain delay (not consistent), the app frame becomes non-responsive and does not handle any of the events. I have put up a `wxTimer` to figure out the amount of time it takes and it varies between 28 seconds to 60 seconds. This is where the timer events are also not called. Now when I press on the `x` or maximize icon on the window, all the pending events are sent and the application becomes active again. 
Here are the options I tried:

- Called `wxTheApp->ProcessPendingEvents();` on the timer (runs every 1 second)
- Tried and looked into `onIdle` method. This is also getting paused after a while

My guess is that the application main thread is paused for some reason and is not able to revert back unless any of the UI actions are triggering it.

Comment: What is the structure of your application? I.e. does it use wx event loop at all?

Comment: @Nareshkumar, what version CEF? Are you using CEF branch of wx?

Comment: @Igor CEF - `76.1.13` and wx - `v3.1.3`

Comment: @VZ. it uses wx event loop and pumps the CEF events via `CefDoLoopWork` via a timer. (runs every 10 ms)

Comment: @Nareshkumar, check wx repository. There was GSoC project to bring CEF API to wx. Unfortunately, it is not complete, but if you grab the current Git master, check out the branch and build the CEF sample - you might be able to figure out what's wrong with your code.

Comment: If it uses wx event loop, there should be no need to call `ProcessPendingEvents()` (or `wxWakeUpIdle()`, which would be better if you had to call it) at all. The only way it can hang in this case is if `CefDoLoopWork()` doesn't return but unfortunately I have no idea why wouldn't it -- all I can say is that it's probably something on CEF end, and not related to wx per se.